# nested dictionary comprehension - adding if condition

Tags: python

I need to add an in statement, something along the list of `list(vs) if type(vs, str)`

```py
d={'int':["unit", "bool"], 'timestamp':"pruct"}

{v: k
 for k, vs in d.items()
 for v in vs}
```

I need this output

```
{'unit': 'int', 'bool': 'int', 'pruct': 'timestamp'}
```

but I'm getting

```
{'unit': 'int',
 'bool': 'int',
 'p': 'timestamp',
 'r': 'timestamp',
 'u': 'timestamp',
 'c': 'timestamp',
 't': 'timestamp'}
```

Comment: If you change your starting dictionary to have ["pruct"]? You are just missing the concept of iterable here. In one case ("unit") the value iterable is a list, in the other ("timestamp") the value iterable is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using dictionary comprehension this should work for you:

```
{v: k
 for k, vs in d.items()
 for v in ([vs] if type(vs) is str else vs)}
```

However, do not forget that

> Simple is better than complex
> ...
> Readability counts
>
> - [The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/)

Comment: using always_iterable as suggested by @wjandrea is the neatest solution but the question was about how to add a conditional if condition and this answers that as well the scenario provided

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my comment to the original question, here you go:

```
def listify_if_necessary(x):
    return [x] if isinstance(x, str) else x

{v: k for k, vs in d.items() for v in listify_if_necessary(vs)}
```

Out:

```
{'unit': 'int', 'bool': 'int', 'pruct': 'timestamp'}
```

Note, as wjandrea pointed out, this `listify_if_necessary` can be replaced by `always_iterable()`.

Comment: [Avoid named lambdas](/q/38381556/4518341), use a `def` instead, or just move the conditional expression into the comprehension like in [itroulli's answer](/a/74229036/4518341). Or use [`always_iterable()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.always_iterable) from `more_itertools`.

Comment: @wjandrea agree with you. It was a fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
new_dict = {}
for key, item in d.items():
    if type(item) is list:
        for i in item:
            new_dict[i] = key
    elif type(item) is str:
        new_dict[item] = key

print(new_dict)
```

Output:
`{'unit': 'int', 'bool': 'int', 'pruct': 'timestamp'}`